# "start" and "stop " missing of update-rc.d command

Tags: mount, umount

I noticed that Ubuntu is slowing down at restarting process after I set in `/etc/fstab` auto mount NAS directory using cifs.

The solution is found in this thread by Help Ubuntu [MountWindowsSharesPermanently](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/MountWindowsSharesPermanently), but warning message are shown.

It seems that "start" and "stop" options of `update-rc.d` command are deprecated.

What should I do use alternative option?

Comment: Does the solution actually work, in spite of the warnings? What version of Ubuntu are you using?

Comment: I checked lsb_release ,

Comment: Distributor ID: Ubuntu
Description: Ubuntu 16.04.2 LTS
Release: 16.04
Codename: xenial